# Simple-iphone-image-processing source code question, what does this do

Tags: c++, iphone, c, objective-c, image-manipulation

I am going through the source code for the above project and I don't understand the following lines of code can anyone help explain it to me please? I am trying to get the code to work with color images as it currently only works with greyscale images. I have the main methods working however the filters only get applied to the top quarter of the returned images.

//In the heeder file.

```
inline uint8_t* operator[](const int rowIndex) {
    return m_yptrs[rowIndex];
}
```

//in the .mm file

```
void Image::initYptrs() {
m_yptrs=(uint8_t **) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t *)*m_height);
for(int i=0; i<m_height; i++) {
    m_yptrs[i]=m_imageData+i*m_width;
    }
}
```

From my understanding it looks like it is creating a a reference to the pixels in the images however i don't understand this line of code.

```
m_yptrs[i]=m_imageData+i*m_width;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image::initYptrs()` initializes an array of pointers to the beginning of each row of the image.

The line in question should probably read

```
m_yptrs[i] = m_imageData + i*BPP*m_width;
```

Where BPP is bytes per pixel (e.g. 3 for RGB, 4 for RGBA images).

Comment: Thanks that explains exactly what i needed to know.
I now have the gaussian blur working in color! 
Thanks again